# What's the quickest way to get rid of larvaes and [clothing] moths at home?

Tags: pest-control, maintenance, humidity

We've moved to this apartment two months ago. The apartment was apparently repainted, while the building is no older than 10 years, but every single part of seems intact for all these years. I've been trying to clean eveywhere, but not fully done, yet.

Since day 1 I've been noticing small "*fluff*"s on walls and ceilings, the back side of wooden drawers (where they have this thin raw-wood-looking layer), and corners of the carpet in the bedroom [that is the only room with a fitted carpet and have been very curious about them, until I've just recently learnt that they're larvae, the baby(?) of the random flying moth we happen to see here and there, and that it's too late when one actually happens to see the flying moths, since it's the larvae that eats stuff, before turning into a moth.

Growing with Persian carpets, we've always had special powder killers to protect the expensive hand-woven carpets, that are informally called "carpet powder/poison", and never even had so many moths in real life! However I don't have access to that specific powder at the moment, and I don't know what actual chemicals it's got in it.

**What I've done so far is:**

1. regularly vacuuming the house, trying to get rid of those fluffs as much as possible (before knowing how damaging they can be).
2. spraying the two cans of "ant killer" and "fly & mosquito killer"s after cleaning every single corner (just after moving), and on a [somewhat] regular basis, but ***mainly to get rid of spiders*** that seem to an undetachable part of daily life here, and I haven't found them so strong.
3. hanging *wardrobe dehumidifiers* in each wardrobe that consist of a pack of silicon balls that absorb humidity and melt in the container, each of which last for a month.
4. running the electric dehumidifier that can suck something like 2, 3 liters of water in every several hours of running (not running it too frequently since it's slightly noisy and not welcomed during hours after work!)
5. reading a lot of articles online about this creature and [ways of fighting against them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tineola_bisselliella#Pest_control). Additionally I've checked several products on Amazon, etc. and obviously all of them claim they have the best solution to this issue.

**What I would like to learn:**

is the quickest (and possibly the cheapest) way of getting a rescue from these little annoying creatures despite the articles that mention once the larvae is there, it's too difficult to immune the whole area and kill them all.

***Note:*** We have a small "room" that contains the hot press, and the rest of unwanted/unused crap that has a room with gaps around, and I haven't scrubbed it so far, but I've sprayed the killers in there a few times, as well, but I'm still paranoid that it's the lovely home for all the unwanted insects and spiders and crawlies we may have.

The floorings are wooden (mainly) with some nylon carpets that aren't fancy enough for the larvae to eat, tiles in the bathroom, and carpet in one of the bedrooms that was shampooed and vacuumed and lots of its fluff came off during shampooing, which is another clue! and we're located having a nice view of the river/sea from our windows (which means a lot to these creatures!)

**TL;DR:** I need a recommendation on the quickest solution to kill all the larvae and moths that have lived in a house for quite a while without being cleaned. (Some product that can kill spiders is a pro!)

Any brands or specific product names are welcome (if that doesn't break S.E.'s rules).

Comment: I haven't seen either clothing moths or mealworms (other than those raised as petfood) in decades. Of course that's partly because I *don't* stress about spiders, and partly because any bug that comes into the house spends part of its remaining life as a cat toy.

Comment: Pro fumigate or use some bug bombs?

Comment: @keshlam Not having seen moths in decades is independent of not stressing about spiders. (: Having a cat is definitely helpful as you mention. And you probably don't live in a similar climate to mine, as I had never seen these things in my daily life either, before moving here.

Comment: I've only ever dealt with minor infestations of the moths and for those I've used pheromone traps.  The goal of those is to trap the adult months before they lay more eggs.  With heavy infestation, I'm not sure if these will make a dent.  Also when the spiders run out of food, the moths, they will move on to a place with more food.

Comment: Dear @downvoter, could you please explain what the downvote was for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't vouch for the effectiveness of this, but here's a link:

http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Moth-Worms

When I've had flea infestations in the past, I've bombed the house, putting a spray can in each room and starting them spraying as I leave. Unfortunately, you have to stay out of the house for a couple of days, and the bomb systems I've looked at don't seem to kill caterpillars, just flying moths.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't know why there's a downvote on this answer or my own question. I was expecting more attention on this question and better answers, however that link has good bits of information that I didn't know. Thanks for taking the time to answer anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

As a tenant I believe you've already done too much as this should be the land lords problem to rectify and not yours.

**Notify the landlord** verbally and in writing about the on going issue of the infestation in your apartment.

**Contact your local city / town / government** about your landlords responsibilities and your rights as a tenant in this type of a situation. Note: It may be possible to break the lease and move out without penalty should the landlord fail to rectify the situation in a certain amount of time.

**If this was your dwelling**: You've done everything you can and unfortunately the situation is beyond DIY and your control.

The best advise anyone can give is to contact an exterminator to have your hone sprayed. The problem with an infestation is that it needs to be addressed all at once, if you clear out one area and move onto another, it's possible that the moths to re-infest the original area and your at square one again. It only takes one for the cycle to start again.

---

> Local hardware shops have only cedar balls (new generation of moth-balls for clothes wardrobes) and spray cans that are useless for a deeper attack. Getting a pest consultant or whatever will NOT count as the desired answer, since I'm not a big fan of spending too much money on this.

Comment: In the case you have provided it is not for **you** the tenant to resolve.

If this was a dwelling that you **owned and you were responsible for** you would still need to **bring in a professional**. The time and effort you've spend trying to eradicate this type of infestation (that has lasted weeks) by purchasing over the counter products and your time will be far more expensive than actually bringing in a professional.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know I've already done too much, but that's what I had to do and considering the climate and culture, this is not something the landlord would do, at least at this level. However I appreciate the time to answer.

Comment: You're welcome - but ultimately my answer is the only solution, we will agree to disagree. I see you're in Ireland. According to the **Citizens Information** website  (http://www.citizensinformation.ie/)  you as a tenant must **Inform the landlord if repairs are needed and give the landlord access to the property to carry out repairs**  In this case an infestation. You are wasting your time and money as it is not your responsibility. Period.